# No Power Options on Upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, power-management, performance

I just upgraded to 22.04 LTS, and I noticed that there are no power performance options like people have been saying in the top menu that has WiFi, Bluetooth, Logout, etc. For me, this is all I have:

[image]

And other people seem to have this:

[image]

And also, there's no option in the GNOME Settings app either, which makes sense since it's not showing up in the top menu. This is a photo of what other people seem to have in the settings app:

[image]

**How do I fix this and get these 3 options?** This problem could be due to the fact that the 22.04 installer crashed and I had to resume the update in the console, but that seemed to have fixed everything and it's all normal now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, I realized that to fix this, you have to install `power-profiles-daemon`.

To install, simply run `sudo apt install power-profiles-daemon`. After that, there's no reboot necessary, as the performance options will already pop up.